# Аналог Photoshop для Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, веб-дизайн, photoshop, поиск-программ

Какой есть аналог Photoshop для Ubuntu, главное чтоб мог открывать psd и работать с слоями. Сейчас использую в качестве альтернативы assets.adobe.com, но с 28,06 самая главная функция Extract отключится

Comment: [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) со скрипом.

Answer (score 12):

Аналогом фотошопа на Ubuntu является GIMP. Само собой, что к некоторым вещам нужно привыкнуть: чего-то в нем нет, что-то сделано иначе. Но это не фотошоп - это аналогичная программа. Как и Ubuntu - это не Windows - сравнивать бессмысленно.

> P.S.: Как бессмысленно сравнение и по цене.

Answer (score 2):

Есть пакет [GIMP Photoshop Tweaks](http://doctormo.deviantart.com/art/Gimp-2-8-Photoshop-Tweaks-432736644) (под лицензией GPLv3), он допиливает gimp до состояния фотошопа: интерфейс, горячие клавиши и расположение окон и вкладок. Я особой разницы не заметил, все как в cs6 только бесплатно и работает шустрее.

Answer (score 1):

Gimp полностью всё умеет из того, что Вам нужно.
По интерфейсу - очень похож на Photoshop.
Всегда есть много мануалов и видео уроков/подсказок

Answer (score 0):

Можно поставить VirtualBox, а на него винду и фотошоп.

По идее, если комп современный, то снижения производительности вы не заметите при работе с виртуалкой....

Answer (score -1):

Поставьте фотошоп на wine и будет вам счастье

Comment: Ставил с помощю wine CS6 и СС но ни одна не работатет корректно, Может кто ставил и осталась ссылка на подходящую версию?

Comment: Какая версия убунты были проблемы в версиях ниже 14, может стоит обновиться?

Comment: Ubuntu 16 , но на винде все эти версии работали нормально

Comment: Странно, у нас весь офис нормально работает, поищу ссылоску...